# PyQt4 Selected Item Text in QTableView delayed by one click

Tags: python, database, pyqt4, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I'm using a `QTableView` to display contents of a `QSqlTableModel` along with using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to filter the records. In the following code I've managed to get the selected text to be displayed when a user clicks the cell (regardless if a filter is applied or not). However, it is always 1 click behind, the first click after start causes an `IndexError: pop from empty list` and when a new column is selected within the same row nothing happens.

I've tried selecting an index after I initialize the table, didn't seems to do anything. I'm out of ideas of what to try next?

```py
class TableViewer(QtGui.QWidget):

    self.model =  QSqlTableModel()
    self._proxyModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self._proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)

    self.tv= QTableView()
    self.tv.setModel(self._proxyModel)

   '''Call-able filter - pass in string to filter everything that doesn't match string'''
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.textEditFilterBox,  QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)"),     self._proxyModel.setFilterRegExp)


     def getItem(self):
         '''Retruns item text of selected item'''
         index = self.selectionModel.selectedIndexes().pop()
         if index.isValid():
             row = index.row()
             column = index.column()
             model = index.model()
             if hasattr(model, 'mapToSource'):
                 #proxy model
                 modelIndex = model.mapToSource(index)
                 print (modelIndex.row(), modelIndex.column())
                 return self.model.record(modelIndex.row()).field(modelIndex.column()).value().toString()
         return self.model.record(row).field(column).value().toString()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    #initialize TableViewer

    self.tblViewer.connect(self.tblViewer.tv.selectionModel(),
            SIGNAL(("currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)")),
            self.tblItemChanged)

    def tblItemChanged(self, index):
        '''display text of selected item '''
        text = self.tblViewer.getItem()
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and when a new column is selected within the same row nothing happens.

That's because you are using `currentRowChanged` signal. That signal won't be fired if you select a column in the same row. You should use `currentChanged` signal.  (and, you should use [new style connections](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html))

And, if you are after just the data, you don't need those stuff to get the non-proxy `QModelIndex` and then ask the model, etc. A `QModelIndex` has a convenience method [`.data`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html#data) that is just for this purpose. Besides, the signal will send you the selected index, you don't need extra work for that. This makes your code as simple as this: (note: `getItem` method is not needed)

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #initialize TableViewer
        self.tblViewer.tv.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.tblItemChanged)

    def tblItemChanged(self, current, previous):
        '''display text of selected item '''
        # `data` defaults to DisplayRole, e.g. the text that is displayed
        print(current.data().toString())
```

Comment: Much simpler and works perfectly, thanks. (I was unaware of the new style, it looks cleaner thanks again.)